# i have 2 input time fields , i want if i enter 01:00 AM in 1st input field time then in 2nd input field time it should be only 02:00AM

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

```html
<tr>
   <td>
   <input  type="hidden" name="date1" class="" value="1"   id="" />Monday
   </td>
   
   <td>
     <input name="starttime" type="time" class="inputext starttime1" value="" style="cursor: text" id="starttime1" required="" />
   </td>
   
   <td>
     <input name="endtime" type="time" class="inputext endtime1" value=""  style="cursor: text; width:34%;" id="endtime1" required="" />
   </td>
   
   <td>
    <input type="button" name="Add"  value="Add" id="add1" class="btn btn-success add"/>
    <a href="{{ url('/viewslots/')}}"><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="View"></a>
     </td>
     
     </tr>
```

**"here i want to validate if i have entered 01:00 AM in start time then in endtime i can only enter 02:00 AM only ie i need 1 hour gap between in these fields only"** 
this is my code but this is working only for if i make my 2nd input field text , this is not working for input field time and i want time field because for exact time in 24 hour or 12 hour.

```js
<script>
       jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     jQuery(document).on('keyup','#starttime1', function(){
      var starttime  =  $(this).val();
      increaseTimeByOne(starttime);
      });
     function increaseTimeByOne(t) {
      var s  = t.split(':');
      var n  = parseInt(s[0],10);
      var nt = (n + 1) + ":00 ";
      console.log(nt)
      var ampm = n >= 11 ? "PM" : "AM";
      if(n>=11){
       var zero = "0";
       var s  = nt.split(':');
       var n  = parseInt(s[0],10);
       var nt = +n;
       var data =  nt + ":00 ";
       $("#endtime1").val(data);
       }else{
        $("#endtime1").val(nt);
        }
        }
        }); 
</script>
```

**emphasized text**

Comment: `ie i need 1 hour gap between in these fields only` - why even have the second field when simple math will do,.  In other words why burden the end user when a simple `+1 hours` can be added to any datetime object.  `(new DateTime($startDate))->modify('+1 hours')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function getTime() {
        var starttime1 = document.getElementById('starttime1').value;
        var t = starttime1.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
        var arr1 = starttime1.split(' ');
        var arr2 = arr1['0'].split(':');

        var hr = parseInt(arr2['0']) + 1;
        if (hr < 10) {
            hr = '0' + hr;
        }
        var min = arr2['1'];
        var sec = '00';
        var time2 = hr + ':' + min + ':' + sec + '' + t;
        document.getElementById('endtime1').value = time2;
        
    }
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <input  type="hidden" name="date1" class="" value="1"   id="" />Monday
    </td>

    <td>
        <input name="starttime" type="time" class="inputext starttime1" value="" style="cursor: text" id="starttime1" required="" />
    </td>

    <td>
        <input name="endtime" type="time" class="inputext endtime1" value=""  style="cursor: text; width:34%;" id="endtime1" required="" onclick="getTime();" />
    </td>

    <td>
        <input type="button" name="Add"  value="Add" id="add1" class="btn btn-success add"/>
        <a href="{{ url('/viewslots/')}}"><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="View"></a>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Omi but can you tell me how can i make the end time field non changeable like disabled or anything else ?

and if i make the end time disabled then i cant perform the 1 hour addition action.

please tell something how to make it non changeable after i enter time on start time.

Comment: Yes @AmitSankhyan , Please add attribute " readonly='readonly' " in end time element.